# TCP tunable parameters in Solaris non-global zone

Tags: solaris, tcp, zones

I'm modifying some TCP parameters in an exclusive-IP non-global zone on Solaris.
I've set the parameters via ndd, like `tcp_recv_hiwat, tcp_xmit_hiwat`, etc.

I want these changes to persist during reboots, but the /etc/system file is not in a non-global zone. Can I use rc.d startup script, or is there another way to apply these settings on reboot of zone?

Answer (score 1):

I would not use an rc.d startup script anymore. The new way to do this since Solaris 10 is an SMF service.

To get started you can find a SMF service template at [http://opensolaris.org/os/community/smf/manifests](http://opensolaris.org/os/community/smf/manifests/). Look for 'site/ndd'. The XML file has further instructions about how to use it as a service.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an appropriately-symlinked script to /etc/init.d is probably the easiest way to achieve what you want.  Instructions [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/816-0607/6m735r5g8/index.html).

You might be able to create a SMF service to do the same thing, but it's a tad more complicated (and I've not attempted to do it inside a zone).  If you want to try anyway, you should be able to use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19261-01/820-2760/ds-os-tuning/index.html#6nebe2km1) as a starting point (Look for the "Tuning TCP Settings on Solaris 10 Systems" section).